# Keeping config files synced in an encfs-encrypted dropbox

Tags: linux, backup, sync, encryption, dropbox

I using my Dropbox to sync my config files on different machines. In addition my Dropbox is synced with encfs. encfs mounts a volume with the decrypted Dropbox-folder on startup. This process takes a while. This is not a problem for config files like `.vimrc` or `.bashrc` or something because I am not using this programs directly during startup. I just use a simple

```
cd && ln -s DecryptedDropbox/.vimrc
```

to link them. And `.vimrc` is available as soon as the decrypted Dropbox is mounted.

However, I use some config files which are important for the startup process like config files for my windowmanager i.e. `.i3/`.

Would it be possible to local version of `.i3` on my hard drive that  syncs with Dropbox as soon as it is available? Of course I also want the Dropbox version changed if I change the local version. I think hard links would not work here since there not really to copys of my file, right? Any other ideas? rsync?

Comment: So, your problem is that Dropbox isn't starting up soon enough and sync'ing your config files soon enough? (soon enough for your window manager?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in the dropbox folder are real files. You should be able to hard link them, but it might not be the best way of doing things. If the files are very small then a simple cron script to copy them once every few minutes might be the simplest and most robust solution here.

Comment: Last I checked, Dropbox's file-change algorithm didn't notice changes to files that are hard linked both in and out of the Dropbox directory.

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

1. **Keeping Dropbox:** The easiest solution would be to keep these files in a non-encrypted part of your Dropbox, I assume there is no reason to have your WM config files encrypted. You can then just do a simple soft link as you describe for `.vimrc`. If it is the encryption that is causing you problems, that should fix it.

   If you are committed to using Dropbox and can't have any part of it unencrypted, I don't see how you could combine it with `rsync`. As far as I know Dropbox does not offer any `ssh` or other access, only its own client.
2. **Ditching Dropbox:** If, on the other hand, you don't *need* to use Dropbox but just want to copy certain configuration files from a remote server *only* if those files are newer than the local copies, yes you can use `rsync`. If you have passwordless ssh access set up between the server and the local machine, you should be able to copy the relevant files with this command:

   rsync -uza user@remote.com:/home/user/.ie3/ .ie3/

   Note the slash at the end of each directory, that tells `rsync` to copy the directories' *content* and not the folders themselves. This is so you don't end up with a local `~/.ie3/.ie3/`.

   From `man rsync`:

   ```
   -u, --update
     This  forces  rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and
     have a modified time that is newer than the source file.  (If an existing
     destination file has a modification  time  equal  to  the source file’s, 
     it will be updated if the sizes are different.)

   -z, --compress
     With  this  option,  rsync  compresses the file data as it is sent to the 
     destination machine, which reduces the amount of data being transmitted --
     something that is useful over a slow connection.

   -a, --archive <- this preserves mod. times, permissions etc.
     This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you want 
     recursion and want to preserve almost everything.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are these config files really required to be encrypted? I don't see what a .vimrc could hold as secret.

Also, I don't think DropBox is the best solution for cloud storing config files. They don't change too often, and DropBox doesn't provide proper compare and merge features and only store older versions for 1 month.

I use Subversion for that. I have a Subversion project where I store many config files: Classic Shell, gtkrc, WinPatrol, FireFox profiles.ini, Sandboxie.ini, vimrc, etc etc.

Since these files aren't changed often and are plain text files, Subversion handles them nicely. WinMerge offers a great GUI for comparing versions so that I can see what changed.

Some files can be stored live, as mpc-hc.ini. Others sadly I need to manually copy when I change them.

For cloud storage I use plan.io.